# Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.build-scan', version: '1.16'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I am trying to do a gradle build scan in my Android project for which I followed this link.

https://scans.gradle.com/

This is my top level gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.16'
}
buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
}
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    zendeskSdkVersion = "2.0.0"
    appCompatVersion = "27.0.2"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I am getting this error when I try to sync project with gradle files

```
Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.build-scan', version: '1.16'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.gradle.build-scan:com.gradle.build-scan.gradle.plugin:1.16')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
Open File
```

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: @SayedAbolfazlFatemi I think I reinstalled studio. That was how it went away

Comment: I had this problem, in my case it was the `repositories` in `settings.gradle` pointing somewhere crazy. (this is probably not the case for the OP here, but this may help future visitors)

Comment: I got same error while migrating from Gradle 4.10.3 to Gradle 6.8